# Hare Tortoise Race Visual Display

Tags: java, oop, switch-statement

I'm doing a project using object-oriented programming where I race a tortoise and a hare along a horizontal course. I've seen other versions using applets and swing, but I haven't been introduced to those yet, so I'd prefer to stay with simpler graphics.

Each animal has a set of moves that occur x percent of the time (I'll elaborate later on).

For the hare, there are five methods: BigHop() - move 9 squares right, SmallHop() - 1 square right, BigSlip() - 12 squares left, SmallSlip() - 2 squares left, and FallAsleep() - no activity at all. Now, the "most left" position is 1, so if the hare is at the 6th square, a big slip will still only get it back to 1. (not -6)

For the tortoise, there are three methods: FastPlod() - 3 squares right, SlowPlod() - 1 square right, and Slip() - 6 squares left with the same rule applying to slips.

The program so far contains a Hare class, a Tortoise class, and a Race class.

Here is the Hare class:

```
 public class Hare {
        private int position;

        public void setPosition(int s){
            position = s;
        }

        public int getPosition(){
            return position;
        }

        public void BigHop(){
            position += 9;
        }

        public void SmallHop(){
            position += 1;
        }

        public void BigSlip(){
            if (position > 12){
                position -= 12;
            }
            else{
                position = 1;
            }
        }

        public void SmallSlip(){
            if (position > 2){
                position -= 2;
            }
            else{
                position = 1;
            }
        }

        public void FallAsleep(){
            position = position;
        }
    }
```

The tortoise class:

```
public class Tortoise {
    private int position;

    public void setPosition(int s){
        position = s;
    }

    public int getPosition(){
        return position;
    }

    public void FastPlod(){
        position += 3;
    }

    public void SlowPlod(){
        position += 1;
    }


    public void Slip(){
        if (position > 6){
            position -= 6;
        }
        else{
            position = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The Race class actually executes the race.

```
public class Race {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Hare myHare = new Hare();
        Tortoise myTortoise = new Tortoise();

        myHare.setPosition(1);
        myTortoise.setPosition(1);

        System.out.println("AND THEY'RE OFF!!");

        while (myHare.getPosition() > 0){
            int n = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            switch (n){
                case 1:
                    myHare.BigHop();
                    myTortoise.FastPlod();
                case 2:
                    myHare.BigHop();
                    myTortoise.FastPlod();
                case 3:
                    myHare.SmallHop();
                    myTortoise.FastPlod();
                case 4:
                    myHare.SmallHop();
                    myTortoise.FastPlod();
                case 5:
                    myHare.SmallHop();
                    myTortoise.FastPlod();
                case 6:
                    myHare.BigSlip();
                    myTortoise.SlowPlod();
                case 7:
                    myHare.SmallSlip();
                    myTortoise.SlowPlod();
                case 8:
                    myHare.SmallSlip();
                    myTortoise.SlowPlod();
                case 9:
                    myHare.FallAsleep();
                    myTortoise.Slip();
                case 10:
                    myHare.FallAsleep();
                    myTortoise.Slip();
            }
            if (myHare.getPosition() == myTortoise.getPosition()){
                System.out.println("OUCH!!");
            }
            if (myHare.getPosition() == 50 | myTortoise.getPosition() == 50){
                if (myHare.getPosition() == 50){
                    System.out.println("HARE WINS!!");
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    if (myHare.getPosition() == myTortoise.getPosition()){
                        System.out.println("IT'S A TIE!!");
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("TORTOISE WINS!!");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The logic itself works. The way the race is constructed is that there are fifty spaces on the track (the track itself hasn't been graphically constructed, which is the trouble I am having). Each animal's moves are executed randomly using the `switch` construct. For example, 30% of the time, the tortoise will SlowPlod().

It takes a while to run just because there are so many slips, but eventually I get a winner (usually the tortoise). So, the logic itself works.

But, right now this is the only output that I display:

`AND THEY'RE OFF!!
TORTOISE WINS!!`

This is of course, without all of the hundreds of "OUCH!!" 's that occur when the two animals share the same position. So I want to be able to display the two animals positions on a track of 50 spaces. I've thought of using '_' as each space, but I'm not sure how to code the movement of the tortoise or the hare.

For example, a possible output would be like this:

`_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ T _ _ _
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ H _ _ _`

`OUCH!!`

I'm just not sure how to construct a track like that and code the movement of the T and the H.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm sorry if my capitalization messed up the highlighting. Still new to Java.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you missed out `break;`'s in your `switch`.

```
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                myHare.BigHop();
                myTortoise.FastPlod();
                break;
            case 2:
                myHare.BigHop();
                myTortoise.FastPlod();
                break;
            ...
            }
```

You're going to need to write another method in `Race` class.

```
private static void printTrack(Player player, char symbol) {
    int position = player.getPosition();
    for (int i = 0; i < position; i++)
        System.out.print('_');

    System.out.print(symbol);

    for (int i = position + 1; i < 50; i++)
        System.out.print('_');

    System.out.println();
}
```

But before that, you need to make a (abstract) class or an interface named `Player`, and modify the classes `Hare` and `Tortoise` to be inherited from `Player`.

```
public abstract class Player {
    protected int position;

    public void setPosition(int s){
        position = s;
    }

    public int getPosition(){
        return position;
    }
}
```

Modify `Hare` and `Tortoise` as following

```
public class Hare extends Player {
    /* 
    private int position;

    public void setPosition(int s){
        position = s;
    }

    public int getPosition(){
        return position;
    }
    */
    // The rest should be the same
    // Do the same with the class "Tortoise"
    ...
}
```

Right after the `switch`, you can call the method.

```
        switch (n) {
            ...
        }
        printTrack(myHare, 'H');
        printTrack(myTortoise, 'T');
        ...
```

And there's a `|` operator somewhere in your code. You need to replace it with `||`.

See if this works.

Comment: If I break the loop each time, then the program becomes useless, right? Because I need to keep running it until one of the animals reaches 50. If I break it each time, then there would only be one movement per animal.

Comment: The break is for the switch statement. If you don't break, every statement in cases in your code below the one you want will also be executed. So, right now, the Hare is falling asleep and the Tortoise is slipping on every move (case 10), along with a number of other actions, which is not what you want.

Comment: Actually `break` keyword inside `switch` doesn't break the loop. It breaks out of `switch`. You need to use `break` keyword before another `case` label, otherwise the code below other `case` labels also gets to be run. Of course, only if you didn't intend that.

Comment: Oh ok. Right sorry I forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a print statement in a decision/repetition structure. You can loop through each possible position, and if the animal is at that position, print the appropriate letter, otherwise print an underscore.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= maxPos; i++) {
    if (i == myTortoise.getPosition())
        System.out.print("T")
    else
        System.out.print("_")
    System.out.print(" ")
}
System.out.println()
```

The above code will print the Tortoise's progress; substitute in `myHare` and `"H"` for the Hare. Insert this code at the top or bottom of your while loop to print the progress after each move.

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. If I insert it at the bottom will I have to insert an initial iteration at the top?

Comment: Yes. An even better solution would be to put it in a function `private static void printProgress` and call it both before the loop and at the end of the loop.

Comment: I tried your code, and it works pretty well, but I'm getting this one glitch where in the last frame (where the winner would be decided), the program automatically shifts both animals to the last position and declares the hare the winner. So, now, every single time, the hare is the winner. Any tips?

Comment: Did you accidentally put in a `setPosition()`? Not sure how else, based on your code, they would both "teleport" at the last frame.

Comment: The only `setPosition()` I put was at the beginning where the two are set to the first position. Could it be an error in the while loop?

Comment: Ok I found the issue. I accidentally added a setPosition() statement saying that if the computer set the animals' positions to above 50, then they would be equal to 50. This is necessary for my next if statements to work (to decide the winner), because if neither of them hit 50, then there is no winner. Do you have any idea on how else I can implement this? I fixed it to the point where there is still a winner, but some times the winner is not shown on the track because they are let's say at square 64.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Swing or some sort of graphical interface the only thing you can do is print the positions over and over again. But that will of course spam your console.

Suppose you don't mind your console getting spammed you could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    printPositions(3, 3, 10);
}

public static void printPositions(int hare, int tortoise, int totalTrackLenght){
    //print the position of hare
    for(int i = 1; i < hare; i++){//print leading empty spaces
        System.out.print("_ ");
    }
    System.out.print("H ");//print hare
    for(int i = hare; i < totalTrackLenght; i++){//print trailing empty spaces
        System.out.print("_ ");
    }
    //print the postion of tortoise in a similar way
    System.out.println();//remember to start on a new line
    for(int i = 1; i < tortoise; i++){//print leading empty spaces
        System.out.print("_ ");
    }
    System.out.print("T ");//print tortoise
    for(int i = tortoise; i < totalTrackLenght; i++){//print trailing empty spaces
        System.out.print("_ ");
    }
    System.out.println();//finish the line
    if(hare == tortoise){//Are they in the same spot?
        System.out.println("OUCH!");
    }
}
```

This method can be called from your 'main loop' for each frame.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this and see what comes up.